# How to make a checkbox inside ModelMultipleChoiceField filled depending on the value in the DB Django

Tags: django

The Plugins model contains information about existing plugins. The UserPlugins model contains summary information about which user has which plugins activated, the activation of the user's plugins  depends on the isActive field.
IisActive field has the value True or False, depending on whether the user has activated the plugin or not. How do I change the checkbox value to checked in ModelMultipleChoiceField if isActive is True in the DB?

models.py

```
class Plugin(models.Model):
    plugin_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True)
    plugin_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    isDisplay = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.plugin_name}"


class UserPlugins(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plugins = models.ForeignKey(Plugin, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

forms.py

```
class UserPluginForm(forms.Form):
    model = UserPlugins
    fields = ['plugins', 'isActive']
    plugins = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                        queryset=Plugin.objects.all(),
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                    )
```

I tried using initial in views, but in the end nothing worked. When going to another page and returning back, the values are reset
views.py

```
def userPluginsSettings(request):
    form = UserPluginForm(request.POST, initial={
        'plugins': [idx for idx in UserPlugins.objects.all()]
    })
    if request.POST.get('plugins'):
        plugins_id_list = request.POST.getlist('plugins')
        plugins = UserPlugins.objects.all()
        for plugin in plugins:
            if str(plugin.plugins_id) in plugins_id_list:
                plugin.isActive = True
            else:
                plugin.isActive = False
            plugin.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, "profile/plugin_list.html",context)
```

template.html

```
<form method="POST" class="home_main_unit" style="flex-direction:column;">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.plugins }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What do I need to do so that the checkbox value in ModelMultipleChoiceField changes to checked depending on the value of isActive?

Comment: Let's say you have "Plugin1" and "Plugin2" both assigned to user "Osmium". Plugin1 is activated, Plugin2 is not. Your code right now can not do that via `UserPlugins.isActive` because the `UserPlugins` does not represent one field but the entire collection of Plugins. If I understand correctly it makes more sense to put the `isActive`field to the `Plugin` itself.